# TCP connection Establishment and Connection Reset ECONNRESET

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am trying to establish a TCP connection between the 2 sockets using

```
SINT32 ret = connect ( sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_ip, sizeof (server_ip ) );
```

I always get the ret = 0 and errno = 0, which should imply that connection was established. Then, i am trying to set the socket options using

```
if  ( ret == 0 )
{
    if ( setsockopt ( sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &val, sizeof(SINT32)) < 0)
     printf ( " Unable to set socket option:%d \n",errno);

}
```

I am always seeing this printf statement with `errno = 104 ECONNRESET`.

Is there a possibility that connect () can still return a null value without establishing a connection ?

Comment: I don't see how you can reliably know about `ECONNRESET` with that code. You need to call `perror()` or use `errno` or the `strerror()` result in your `printf()` to see that.

Comment: I forgot to add the errno in the post . I also crossed checked from the GDB  of the errno that was returned and it was errno 104.

Comment: Are you doing this in blocking mode?